# A button to change 'javascript:history.go() ' history

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

Usually we use `<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a>` to go back page.

I would like to build a button to increase `-1` value.

For example, when I click a button `history.go(-2)` click again  `history.go(-3)`  like this.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Give it a shot. Write some code. Show some effort.

Comment: @Matt Ball 

Here is the problem [link](http://athimannil.com/mobjob/jobs.php) 

When u click on any job you can see back button as an arrow image. it is work fine like `history.go(-1)` then click on **apply Direct** after that If I want to go back I have click back button twice.


I think the solution is that increase `-1` to `-2` while click on the **Apply Direct** button

Answer (score 1):

<del>Here's an example function using [**closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):</del>

```
<a id="backer" href="">back</a>
...
document.getElementById('backer').onclick = (function () {
  var x = -1;
  return function () {
      console.log(x--)
  }
})();
```

<del>Obviously, replace `console.log` with `history.go`.</del>

---

#### EDIT

I just thought about the fact that this is using the back button. You could use [**cookies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Cookies) for IE7 coverage, but [**localStorage**](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is so much cleaner.

```
<a id="backer" href="">back</a>
...
document.getElementById('backer').onclick = (function () {
  var x = window.localStorage['background'] | 0;
  return function () {
      x = x - 1;       
      window.localStorage['background'] = x;  
      history.back(--x)
  }
})();
```

Comment: here is the link  http://athimannil.com/mobjob/jobs.php. choose a job click **back button** working fine. when u click on **Apply Direct** then u need to click twice to go back to job result page :(

Comment: Note that the local storage link should now point to: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html